# Could not find the Task 'func : host start'

Tags: typescript, azure

I am trying to run azure on my PC. I am using VS Code, Windows 64 bit

I have installed `Azure SDK` - `.NET Core 2.2.x SDK` - `Cosmos Emulator` - `Storage Emulator` and also installed `azure-functions-core-tools V2`

when i try to run debugger by using f5 key , I am getting below error

[image]

Comment: How did you debug? And please use func --version to check the tools.

Comment: Check Prerequisites - https://code.visualstudio.com/tutorials/functions-extension/getting-started

Comment: And about how to debug you could refer to this blog.https://cmatskas.com/debugging-c-net-core-azure-functions-with-vs-code/

Comment: @GeorgeChen ` func --version` is returning 2.7.1373

Comment: @AgrawalShraddha. I have checked. Yeah its installed, but thing is I can't run it by pressing f5, I have to mannualy run `func host start` in VS Code. and my breakpoints are also not working

Comment: @GeorgeChen. Thanks for the link, but i dont think that link would resolve my issue ;-(

Comment: Are you running "func host start" from a terminal window or from the VS Code Run Task option?

Comment: @SamaraSoucy-MSFT I am running from VS Code Run

Answer (score 26):

I fixed this by installing the Azure Functions extension for Visual Studio Code then restarting Visual Studio Code.

Changing terminal did not help.

Comment: better wording here is you uninstall and install the Azure Functions extension and it fixes the issue

Answer (score 9):

I resolved this by ensuring I was connected to Azure. Opening Azure on the side menu (Shift+Alt+A) was sufficient.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem. I started VSCode as an Administrator and debugging worked as expected.

Answer (score 7):

I had Azure Functions extension installed already. Restarting VS Code resolved the issue.

Comment: Xd, the first time I encountered this error this solution didn't help me, now after a while I encountered it again and it worked for me :3

Answer (score 4):

I believe this was because your VSCode instance is set to use version 5.0 of Powershell when debugging.  I followed these instructions on my machine to reference Powershell Core 6 instead and the debugging worked flawlessly afterward.  I intend to put it back for normal development so that I use v5.0 for day-to-day work:

1. In VSCode: Ctrl-Shift-P
2. Preferences: Open User Settings Search
   for: terminal.integrated.shell.windows
3. Save the original value:
   "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
   (for use after you finish playing with Azure Functions In
   Powershell)
4. Replace it with the new value: "c:/Program
   Files/PowerShell/6/pwsh.exe"
5. Save
6. Restart VSCode

Comment: This solved it for me! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If its a fresh installation of VS Code, this happens if the Python Extension is not installed. Install the recommended extensions and this error went away

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the solution was simpler. There was some malformed json code in host.json. As soon as I fixed it, I was able to run the debugger again.

I would review host.json and see if you have the same problem. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have Azure Function Extensions installed correctly, another way you can see this error is if you change the command line arguments in tasks.json, this will change the generated task label. You can solve it by manually setting the label to match the previously generated one.

Example:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "func: host start",
      "type": "func",
      "command": "host start --port 5022",
      "problemMatcher": "$func-node-watch",
      "isBackground": true,
      "dependsOn": "npm build (functions)"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Alternatively you can update the task reference in launch.json to include the command line arguments, but setting the task label will be more resilient to future configuration changes.

Answer (score 0):

This happened when updated the VS code version.

Try uninstalling and reinstalling azure functions extention. It should work then.

Answer (score 0):

One hack that is working is deploying the Azure Functions to a Function app (not used) from VS Code itself. After this, the functions are running/debugging normally after pressing F5. What I infer is that deployment is initiating the right of terminals or resetting some background variables to right values.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue, VSC asked me to install the Azure Functions Core Tools, but after I did, I got the message "Could not find the Task 'func : host start'". This happend each time I pressed F5.

None of the solutions from above worked.But finally, I managed to solve it with [the method described by @ValentinPetkov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65375183/21052833):

```
choco install azure-functions-core-tools-3 --params="'/x64:true'"
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. Compared the tasks.jason file with that of another project that worked fine and found no difference.
Saved my workspace and re-launched vscode. That worked without changing any thing

Comment: this answer has no purpose

Answer (score -1):

I fixed mine using these steps:

1. Press F1, type settings.json to open the local settings.json file.
2. Look for the key "terminal.integrated.automationShell.windows" and update to:

   "terminal.integrated.automationShell.windows": "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe"