# Azure functions core tools installation is stuck in visual studio code

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-function-app, azure-functions-core-tools

I have created Azure function app to execute powershell script. Wanted to run it on my local first to test it. When I run it, with or without debugging option, one popup is coming which says - **"You must have the azure functions core tools installed to debug your local functions."** When I click on Install on this popup, it seems automatically starting installing Azure functions core tools.

But its stuck at one point - **attempting to GET "https://functionscdn.azureedge.net/public/3.0.2534/Azure.Functions.Cli.win-x64.3.0.2534.zip"**

Confirmed my network is good, tried by restarting PC and followed the steps again but no luck.

Other observation is, even If I install it manually using command prompt by using below command,

```
npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@3
```

it still says **"You must have the azure functions core tools installed to debug your local functions."**

Reference is - 
[image]
Can you please guide how to proceed with this?
Thank You.

Comment: As another option, you can try to use hotkeys CTRL+SHIFT+P on Windows or CMD+SHIFT+P on Mac to toggle the command palette. Search for Azure Functions and choose the Azure Functions Core Tools. Choose the correct version for your Function. I hope it helps.

Comment: hi @EugeneD, this github url you provided above is not working

Comment: Hi @Oxygen, I change the URL, thanks for the note, please have a look. You can try to download the executable files directly from [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools)  And also please check that you are selecting a correct version for your function.

Comment: Explicit installation works @EugeneD. Thank you so much for the push.

Comment: You are always welcome @Oxygen :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go the Azure Functions Core Tools [release page](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/releases), download MSI file of the version you want, then just install it.

Or you could download the zip file, unzip it then set the folder path to your environment **Path**.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @George. It helped.

Answer (score 3):

After lost a day with all these install uninstall...

**THE MOMENT OF TRUTH** 
**To install the 64-bit version, which allows you to debug, you can use the command**

**here**

choco install azure-functions-core-tools-3 --params="'/x64:true'"

BAM worked I can debug in visual studio code

https://chocolatey.org/packages/azure-functions-core-tools-3#install

the first comment
thanks Tyler Doerksen life saver!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue.

`npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@3`
It doesn't add func to the path.

Adding following to the path resolved the issue.

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm
```